How to type this mathematical symbol, it is not mathbb{d}

The first symbol.,I have tried mathbb,mathbbf,unicode math,

It looks like a d and l put together.

@projetmbc I did wonder about that:-)

It is an “l” next to a “d”.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\dd}{d\mspace{-2.5mu}l}

\begin{document}

\[
\hat{\dd}_{\rho}()
\]

\end{document}


Well, probably the document you have did \hat{\dd_{\rho}}

which I find wrong.
With unicode-math a decent substitute might be U+2146 from the freely available Symbola font.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newfontface{\symbola}{Symbola}
\NewDocumentCommand{\dd}{}{\text{\symbola\symbol{"2146}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\hat{\dd}_{\rho}()
\]

\end{document}



Very nice the option with unicode-math.

If you have the PDF for that you can see exactly what font and character it is but italic double struck d is unicode  U+2146 ⅆ  which is \mitBbbd in unicode-math

I only have the PDF file; can you recommend some tools to see the font?

pdfffonts utility or your pdf reader font menu should tell you the fonts used in the document and just cut and paste that character into anything or into https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html  will tell you which character that is this question is essentially a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture/47035#47035 @shanakchuan

@shanakchuan but as pointed out in comments your document probably has a faked ⅆ  made by putting s d and l together as the authoour couldn't find a correct way to do it, but you do not want to do that, either use a ⅆ  or (better) just use a normal math italic d)

Two methods
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}

\(d\kern -0.12em l\)
\(d\mspace{-2.5mu}l\)%require amsmath package

\end{document}



The first answer comes from @egreg,  thanks.
